# Jquery: Alter alternatives in Select depending on several radiobuttons

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a webform where I want the alternatives in a select/dropdownbox to change depending on which radiobutton the user selects. I've found out how to achieve this, I do it like this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="mainType" id="rbtA" Value="RadiobuttonA" onClick=0>Option 1<br>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="maalertype" id="rbtB" Value="RadiobuttonB" onClick=0>Option 2<br>

<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="subType" id="rbtSubA" Value="SubA" />Sub-option 1
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="subType" id="rbtSubB" Value="SubB" />Sub-option 2

<b>Make your selection: </b><br>
<SELECT id="selectType" style="width: 150" NAME="Spenning">
  <OPTION selected="selected"></OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
var arrayType1=["A", "B", "C"];
var arrayType2=["D", "E", "F"];
var arraySubType1=["A1", "B1"];
var arraySubType2=["C1", "C2"];
var mapType={ rbtA : arrayType1, rbtB : arrayType2 }

$('#rbtA, #rbtB').change(function() {
  $("#selectType option").remove();
  $.each(mapType[this.id], function(i, val) {
    var opt = $("<option />");
    opt.appendTo($("#selectType")).text(val).val(val);
  });
});
```

This works. Now, I want the options in the dropdownbox selectType to change to the alternatives in arraySubType1 or arraySubType2 if the user selects either rbtSubA or rbtSubB. I thought I could do it like this:

```
$('#rbtSubA, #rbtSubB').change(function() {
  if ($('#rbtSubA').is(':checked')){
    //I thought I could do it as simple as changing the content of the value mapType
    mapType={ rbtA : arraySubType1, rbtB : arrayType2 };
    $("#selectType option").remove();
    $.each(mapType[this.id], function(i, val) {
      var opt = $("<option />");
      opt.appendTo($("#selectType")).text(val).val(val);
    });
  }
  if ($('#rbtSubB').is('checked')){
    //vice versa
  }
});
```

Then I ran this in Chrome, and turned on Tools->Developer tools. When I alternate between rbtA and rbtB, the contents of selectType changes, but when I selecet rbtSubA,

I get the error message

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

I cannot see which variable might be undefined here, can anyone see what's wrong in this? Or perhaps this must be done in some oth

Comment: May I suggest [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)..?

Comment: Where is defined mapVoltage ?

Comment: Author has admitted "typos" (3 at least) and has negelected to collect them. -1 for the question until they are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is causing the issue, but you shoudl be looking for the `:checked` pseudoclass selector, not `checked`:

```
if ($('#rbtSubB').is(':checked')){
```

Also, it looks like there is a problem with the following line having an isolated `"`:

```
 mapType={ rbtA : arraySubType1, rbtB : arrayType2" };
```

I'm guessing you want:

```
 mapType={ rbtA : arraySubType1, rbtB : arrayType2 };
```

Given that this is on the 'select A' code, then I suspect it is the source of your error.

Comment: About rbtSuB, the missing colon in front of _checked_ is just a typo here. I haven't stared working on rbtSubB, I need to get rbtSubA to work first. If I can do that, it should be possible to make rbtSubB work exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your code:

- The ids are rbtSubA and rbtSubB, not rbtA and rbtB
- Your using mapVoltage instead of mapType

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
$('#rbtSubA, #rbtSubB').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    //I thought I could do it as simple as changing the content of the value mapType
    mapType={ rbtSubA : arraySubType1, rbtSubB : arraySubType2 };
    $("#selectType option").remove();
    $.each(mapType[this.id], function(i, val) {
      var opt = $("<option />");
      opt.appendTo($("#selectType")).text(val).val(val);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The "voltage" thing is just a typo here, not in my original code. I wanted to make it generic here, not about voltage, but I forgot to rename all variables. I've edited the original example above now, so it should be correct with respect to variable names. The ids might be an issue. I want rbtA to be mapped against arraySubType1 when I select rbtSubA. Furthermore, I had forgotten a line break when I posted the question, not all the html was visible, I've fixed that now.

Comment: Well imho, mapType should be { rbtSubA : arraySubType1, rbtSubB : arrayType2 } in the second sniplet